# Faulty nesting in .heex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

While converting old `.eex` into `.heex` I stumbled upon this code which uses TailwindCSS to display zebra style table rows:

```
<%= for {language, counter} <- Enum.with_index(@languages) do %>
  <tr class="<%= if rem(counter, 2) == 0, do: "bg-white", else: "bg-gray-50" %>">
```

It results into this error while running `mix format`

```
$ mix format
mix format failed for file: lib/w_games_web/templates/language/index.html.heex
** (Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLTokenizer.ParseError) nofile:2:14: expected closing `"` for attribute value
```

I kind of understand the problem and then I don't.

- How can I fix this?
- Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve the wanted zebra code effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With HEEx, HTML attributes have to be generated this way:

```
<tr class={if rem(counter, 2) == 0, do: "bg-white", else: "bg-gray-50"}>
```

In short, `attr="<%= value %>"` (EEx) becomes `attr={value}` (HEEx).

Note: you can use CSS(3) to alternate colors (`:nth-child(odd/even)`) and use the [`Integer.is_odd/even/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Integer.html#is_even/1) guards in Elixir